# Shell Scripting: Using a variable to define a path

Tags: bash, shell, variables, path

My problem lies with my confusion with **shell variables**.

To my understanding, variables allow me to store a value (String in this case) and to call it later in my code.  So if I wanted to have a **variable that holds the path** to some set of scripts, I could ideally just store it like this:

```
SPTH = '/home/Foo/Documents/Programs/ShellScripts/Butler'

//Later on in the script//
cd $SPTH
./script1
```

What I'm trying to do, with probably the wrong syntax, is to set the path to **variable `SPTH`**.

Then I use `cd` with argument `$SPTH`.

Ideally this would allow me to **run the file there without typing in the path**.  However it doesn't work.  The **`$SPTH`** is ignored and the result is as if **`cd`** was used alone.

So what am I doing wrong? And what would be a way to do this?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you don't use spaces surrounding the "=".

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Don't use spaces...

(Incorrect)

```
SPTH = '/home/Foo/Documents/Programs/ShellScripts/Butler'
```

(Correct)

```
SPTH='/home/Foo/Documents/Programs/ShellScripts/Butler'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now works like a charm, I'll have to remember this.

Comment: what if there is a space in the path

Comment: @Eatdoku when using `SPTH` in your script and its value has a space, then surround the variable with double quotes. E.g. `cd "$SPTH"`

Comment: Can this be run without the need for CD? I was thinking `command $SPTH` but that seems somehow risky. Maybe I need to variable the path, but hardcode the script name? `command $SPTH/somescript.sh` ?

Answer (score 6):

To add to the above correct answer :-
For my case in shell, this code worked (working on `sqoop`)

```
ROOT_PATH="path/to/the/folder"
--options-file  $ROOT_PATH/query.txt
```